# Bash functions with globbing and substitution

Tags: bash, escaping, freebsd, glob

I am trying to write a function in bash that will do a find for a directory containing the passed value. Something like this:

```
function dfind () {
   find / -type d -name "*$**"
}
```

What I want is for `dfind test` to execute `find / -type d -name "*test*"`

I've tried escaping the globbing *'s, or the quotes, or both, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Works for me.  "I can't get it to work"  What part of it didn't work for you?  Did it generate an error message?  Did it find the wrong files?  Does it only work on certain file names? Please be clear and specific.

Comment: nothing at all is returned. I type `dfind virtual` and immediately get a prompt.

Comment: `dfind virtual` works for me (on linux).  Try `set -x; dfind virtual`.  What does it show?  (When done, run `set +x` to stop the debug output.)

Comment: `+ find / -type d -name '**' virtual`

Comment: Hmm.  On my machine, it shows `+ find / -type d -name '*virtual*'`.

Comment: FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE-p3 i386 i386 GENERIC. How odd. you just put `"*$**"` in the function? no escaping at all?

Comment: Yes, I copied and pasted directly from your question.  No editing.  (Running Debian Linux with Bash 4.2.37.)

Comment: well, that's annoying. I wonder if it's a BSD difference. Running bash 4.3.30 here.

Comment: OK, never mind. I tried it on a different FreeBSD machine and it worked perfectly, so the issue must not be the function or the shell, but rather something flubber on that first machine. This explains why it also worked on my OS X machine. Off to find the real problem. ugh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the function nor bash, but something wonky on the machine I was using. Identical function works on another FreeBSD machine.

Comment: Try "*${*}*", I wonder if that will work. Sorry, SO is interpreting the * as formatting. " * $ { * } * " w/o spaces

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as accepted so that this question no longer comes up as unresolved. Thanks.

Comment: @Dinesh You can use backticks to post code in a comment. `"*${*}*"`